# Peugeot 208 1.0L 2013 with 58k miles with P0420 even after cat replacement

Tags: p0420

I’ve just gotten my cat replaced under warranty on a Peugeot 208 1.0L 2013 that I bought used with more or less 57k miles around three months ago.

After having rough idle and a P0420 as soon as I bought it, the place I got it from did some investigating and replaced a leaky valve cover which also plugged the PCV valve.
My assumption is that the car burned oil that ended up ruining the old cat.

After that the engine started running much better but the code came back and they concluded it needed a new cat.
The O2 sensors reading looked like in the first screenshot and becoming wavy when revving up the car. So the new cat was installed today.

The problem is that after I got home today I have again the P0240 came back.
I was really hoping that replacing the cat would solve a cat fault code but it doesn’t seem to be the case.

The O2 sensors reading while idling with a warmed up car looks like in the second image, which indicates a bad cat, despite the fact that’s just been replaced.

Can it be that the downstream O2 sensor is toasted? Or maybe the cat is not broken in and not doing its job yet?

I really don’t know what to think anymore.

[image]

[image]